# Why do I need to click reset button twice before the jqueries in it is triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a normal Reset button.

```
 <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
```

When the button is click, there should be other jquery taking effects in the same time.

```
$('[type=reset]').click(function(){
    $('input[name=24hours]:radio').trigger('change');
    $(':checkbox').trigger('change');
});
```

The problem is, I need to press reset button twice before the jquery in `$('[type=reset]').click(function()` are executed. Why does that happened and how to avoid it?

EDIT: Here's the jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/fdvr05s4/9/

Comment: Can you reproduce this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Works fine **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/p00xa1wL/)**

Comment: Added jsfiddle. please review. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I see here is that, `trigger('change')` fires before the form is actually reset. So when you click on reset, it triggers the `change` so nothing happens, then the form resets to the default state. Now on your second reset, the form is already in its default state, hence the `change` trigger now works as you expect.

Try this solution instead. By using this we make sure that the form is already reset before firing `change`:

```
$('[type=button]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('form')[0].reset();
    $('input[name=yesno]:radio').trigger('change');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fdvr05s4/10/

Comment: So that's it! Thank you!.